# Keras embedding layer with LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

My original model is:

```
input = Input(shape=(1, 6)) # 1 time step, 6 features
LSTM_layer = LSTM(self.lstm_units, return_sequences=False, return_state=True)
lstm_output, out_h, out_c = LSTM_layer(embedded, initial_state=[h, c])
```

The input is a one hot vector, eg [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Now I've read that it's better to embed inputs to LSTM, so the model now looks like

```
input = Input(shape=(6,))
embedded = Embedding(6, 2, input_length=6)(input)
LSTM_layer = LSTM(self.lstm_units, return_sequences=False, return_state=True)
lstm_output, out_h, out_c = LSTM_layer(embedded, initial_state=[h, c])
```

While this works, my question is, the output from embedding layer is now (?, 6, 2).  Which is 6 time steps and 2 features in the eyes of LSTM layer.  Is this the correct way to implement such a method?

Comment: Can you explain, what you want to do? Why you want to embed the inputs?

Comment: @Digital-Thinking I'm trying to implement ENAS (https://github.com/melodyguan/enas).  Although the dimension of the input is quite low to justify using embedding layer, they seem to have used it anyway.  Plus, it would be good to know how to solve this issue anyway.